# Android Range Seekbar with two different thumbs

Tags: android-studio, seekbar, android-seekbar, seekbar-thumb, rangeseekbar

I want a range seekbar with two different thumb range selections.

I'm using this library but there is not an option right drawable only the left drawable is working on both ends.

```
<org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
                                    android:id="@+id/rangeSeekBar_"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:visibility="visible"
                                    app:thumbPressed="@drawable/ic_seeker"
                                    app:thumbNormal="@drawable/ic_seeker"
                                    app:showLabels="false"
                               />
```

is there any other library or workaround please help
Complete solutions are also welcome of course ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use material design Sliders for that.

Add Google's Maven Repository google() in build.gradle. For example:

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
    }
  }
```

Add the library to the dependencies section:

```
 dependencies {
// ...
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
// ...
 }
```

In the layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
  android:id="@+id/range_slider"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:contentDescription="@string/slider_desc"
  app:values="@array/initial_slider_values"
  android:valueFrom="0.0"
  android:valueTo="100.0" />
```

For more details: https://material.io/components/sliders/android#continuous-slider

Comment: unable to add two different drawable for left and right

Answer (score 0):

Try with this range seekbar: https://github.com/YahooArchive/android-range-seek-bar

Dependency:

> implementation
> 'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-
>
> library:0.1.0'